# Android - Application Manager - Disable multiple apps at once?

Tags: automation, bloatware, application-manager

Let me first say I am not an Android person and new to this. I am needing to disable applications on 300+ devices. I have a list that they want disabled, now I've been just manually going in and swiping each one to disable them, but this is very time consuming. There has to be an easier way.  I was thinking with profile I could make and download it off the internet on each one or each device is encrypted with Mobile Iron, is there something to push to the device's to do this this.  My searching has shown nothing useful.

Thanks,

Tablets are LG VK815
Android version 5.0.2

Answer (score 2):

You can hook the tablets one-by-one up to a computer with ADB drivers installed and USB debugging turned on in the tablets' settings, and run a .bat file with the list of stuff to disable which will look like this:

```
adb shell pm disable com.trash.application
adb shell pm disable com.more.bloatware
[...]
```

It's that easy! Root may be required depending on device.

Here's an example on XDA: [Bloatware disable in .bat file](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=15987140&postcount=7)

Comment: Aaron this is helpful, how do I know what the "com.mspot.android.music.mspotradiosprint" part is.  These are business devices and only are used for one app, everything else is to be disabled. Example Music, Hangouts, Google+ and a lot other native apps. I don't want to root these devices.

Comment: Type `pm list packages` in adb and it will spit out all of the packages, ready for you to maneuver your way through. Make sure not to disable anything system related, just the apps you know aren't necessary.

Comment: If your device won't let you disable some of the apps, I would highly recommend rooting it. In fact, there is one-click-root available for VK815, here: [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/general/guide-root-lg-firmwares-kitkat-lollipop-t3056951) You'll be plugging in all the tablets to your computer anyway. Rooting is really easy, trust me. You will have a lot more control over your tablets, like hiding the Settings app, turning off quick settings in notification bar (so people don't steal your tablets after turning on airplane mode etc.)

Comment: These are devices with Mobile Iron on them and are used for nurses. I cant root them, the MDM wont allow that.

I've not got the ADB  way to work, but I would still have to go into each device and put it to dev mode. Thats steps almost as equal of me setting up each device myself manually.

Comment: Each device is brand new, so I have to take it out of the box, turn it on, go through the LG setup menus (just skip, skip, skip etc), manually set wifi, and disable 22 native applications, as these devices are strictly to be used for patient data charting, no youtube, play store, games etc.

Right now I've got about 75 done of 300, it was a slow day today. Wish me luck :)

Comment: Good luck! If only people knew that rooting does not breach security, it adds to it... Unrooted, any app could really have a root method built in to it (Towelroot, Framaroot) to gain root access without the security layer of SuperSU blocking the access after rooting manually. I guess it technically violates the DMCA.

Answer (score 1):

If the devices are rooted then you can try [ROM Toolbox Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.liberty.toolbox) app.
Otherwise, I think you are out of luck since disabling applications is a feature which requires root access unless done through Settings app.

**Note:** Most Android builds don't consist of many pre-installed system applications. If the application is not a system application it can only be uninstalled or frozen, not disabled.